# RS-232 Communication with Python Returning Gibberish

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I've recently been trying to control an OceanOptics HR4000 spectrometer via RS-232 connection. I've tested the serial commands (provided here: http://www.oceanoptics.com/technical/engineering/OEM%20Data%20Sheet%20--%20HR4000.pdf) with Termite, a serial console, and they work just as expected. Therefore, I'm sure my physical connections are all correct. However, when writing these commands to the serial device using PySerial, the return is not what I expect but instead some gibberish.

Here is what I get with Termite, and what I want to get with Python:

```
a[06]

>
[15]

>I200
[06]

>S[02]
[15]

>65535 0 0 3 3 3392 0 2275 1938 1995 2049 2348 2324 2259 2294 2266 2338 2272 2276 2218 2396 2314 2293 2317 2442 2308 2299 2341 2306 2252 2270 2258 2349 2295 2279 2311 2289 2248 2282 2343 2298 2235 2287 2318 2291 2317 2241 2246 2256 2291 2251 2274 2229 2288 2269 2334 2285 2214 2293 2293 2268 2290 2305 2324 2281 2268 2305 2258 2343 2341 2281 2264 2258 2286 2351 2295 2281 2274 2294 2292 2381 2302 2287 2397 2327 2259 2351 2266 2282 2366 2243 2305 2355 2309 2243 2233 2276 2262 2258 2272 2230 2262 2212 2270 2347 2241 2273 2267 2377 2348 2323 2252 2285 2291 2313 2229 2298 2264 2299 2276 2376 2276 2277 2436 2267 2259 2314 2325 2219 2277 2256 2338 2292 2335 2229 2233 2280 2301 2232 2406 2311 2271 2274 2301 2365 2302 2302 2351 2340 2287 2292 2307 2293 2302 2250 2315 2334 2282 2298 2393 2337 2267 2259 2356 2348 2304 2279 2319 2282 2310 2254 2366 2375 2284 2256 2270 2271 2259 2288 2263 2229 2261 2294 2265 2328 2286 2249 2414 2311 2262 2263 2307 2278 2349 2331 2352 2236 2254 2275 2348 2390 2329 2271 2300 2248 2330 2310 2300 2298 2272 2220 2357 2388 2261 2253 2336 2317 2322 2322 2348 2299 2295 2305 2337 2299 2263 2321 2284 2301 2349 2317 2256 2325 2259 2288 2274 2342 2387 2288 2292 2293 2294 2272 2229 2268 2316 2277 2362 2245 2284 2283 2374 2272 2292 2246 2232 2253 2252 2279 2242 2276 2254 2273 2232 2299 2278 2298 2393 2366 2277 2251 2286 2270 2252 2267 2329 2354 2244 2319 2385 2329 2320 2292 2354 2284 2287 2307 2271 2370 2238 2308 2314 2337 2265 2246 2282 2373 2258 2315 2273 2312 2327 2322 2359 2383 2266 2226 2237 2319 2270 2267 2305 2286 2251 2263 2288 2272 2288 2266 2249 2351 2326 2301 2243 2353 2258 2261 2403 2308 2300 2274 2282 2263 2262 2233 2314 2337 2313 2291 2338 2336 2270 2316 2329 2284 2299 2312 2341 2302 2309 2263 2340 2351 2292 2268 2317 2355 2277 2296 2321 2309 2278 2280 2274 2357 2336 2268 2358 2327 2339 2316 2362 2352 2300 2268 2250 2323 2293 2261 2306 2247 2234 2271 2262 2299 2281 2297 2229 2306 2229 2257 2284 2346 2348 2309 2318 2382 2301 2317 2261 2329 2293 2288 2278 2264 2285 2260 2261 2279 2307 2335 2285 2301 2315 2279 2245 2238 2292 2302 2445 2375 2281 2254 2276 2415 2249 2278 2345 2364 2233 2316 2372 2286 2298 2270 2250 2304 2318 2228 2278 2329 2318 2281 2288 2316 2261 2321 2304 2287 2230 2290 2248 2305 2194 2247 2314 2360 2342 2228 2304 2345 2255 2229 2345 2313 2232 2182 2276 2349 2288 2219 2229 2337 2265 2228 2258 2245 2205 2231 2294 2332 2279 2340 2265 2316 2295 2225 2231 2281 2245 2254 2306 2330 2255 2238 2261 2252 2246 2198 2385 2381 2280 2248 2305 2257 2213 2243 2296 2323 2216 2247 2259 2275 2296 2221 2294 2228 2248 2226 2280 2325 2249 2281 2352 2285 2266 2222 2213 2254 2234 2263 2350 2329 2221 2220 2286 2307 2210 2270 2347 2278 2222 2246 2213 2315 2249 2185 2280 2337 2254 2302 2279 2281 2265 2228 2266 2357 2232 2238 2254 2256 2247 2241 2246 2239 2207 2196 2250 2283 2271 2264 2262 2220 2222 2222 2274 2363 2315 2242 2276 2265 2245 2232 2321 2328 2289 2229 2374 2379 2251 2259 2314 2324 2244 2216 2268 2392 2279 2263 2333 2326 2291 2303 2248 2330 2289 2241 2249 2298 2294 2237 2271 2260 2286 2205 2291 2308 2244 2262 2328 2299 2232 2170 2333 2273 2284 2239 2382 2312 2271 2268 2299 2314 2301 2261 2272 2258 2241 2232 2276 2306 2248 2254 2294 2286 2270 2256 2254 2274 2272 2230 2259 2318 2290 2262 2306 2315 2222 2239 2258 2286 2245 2198 2285 2262 2280 2250 2306 2260 2206 2236 2292 2250 2215 2275 2336 2336 2326 2218 2318 2266 2199 2208 2252 2289 2269 2312 2302 2286 2273 2269 2300 2311 2307 2290 2267 2319 2266 2247 2294 2339 2291 2251 2398 2372 2269 2248 2341 2313 2284 2246 2245 2258 2275 2218 2258 2310 2211 2242 2335 2358 2261 2269 2336 2281 2267 2257 2324 2322 2242 2246 2267 2434 2331 2279 2277 2255 2267 2254 2292 2288 2278 2248 2263 2253 2234 2245 2305 2306 2303 2241 2334 2280 2264 2252 2211 2253 2229 2247 2255 2268 2288 2239 2267 2359 2223 2261 2346 2294 2287 2269 2249 2355 2306 2288 2299 2346 2257 2221 2283 2327 2267 2281 2294 2370 2270 2260 2277 2324 2248 2228 2257 2297 2297 2226 2267 2268 2283 2244 2237 2302 2256 2271 2250 2271 2249 2344 2339 2304 2269 2246 2220 2303 2270 2261 2346 2335 2268 2257 2259 2279 2278 2241 2324 2330 2272 2216 2307 2279 2285 2288 2310 2309 2289 2241 2332 2318 2230 2284 2356 2246 2210 2197 2296 2314 2262 2228 2226 2312 2275 2265 2297 2237 2226 2291 2200 2254 2262 2265 2248 2281 2275 2253 2300 2343 2214 2240 2200 2227 2192 2254 2272 2282 2264 2230 2229 2301 2196 2259 2384 2317 2256 2240 2264 2351 2252 2205 2245 2298 2292 2278 2284 2335 2260 2226 2264 2346 2349 2280 2295 2275 2255 2232 2403 2304 2283 2268 2338 2327 2260 2276 2245 2372 2251 2259 2288 2316 2258 2212 2274 2337 2272 2204 2182 2305 2257 2220 2277 2280 2308 2223 2321 2244 2238 2227 2214 2271 2202 2256 2286 2283 2234 2201 2289 2316 2229 2242 2290 2262 2225 2222 2236 2327 2203 2235 2333 2369 2295 2225 2284 2270 2234 2244 2321 2293 2275 2247 2219 2245 2269 2278 2272 2328 2248 2293 2234 2282 2210 2245 2287 2296 2256 2318 2298 2249 2263 2224 2297 2296 2245 2234 2305 2260 2291 2230 2304 2245 2211 2259 2372 2269 2278 2259 2253 2334 2274 2276 2306 2268 2258 2294 2290 2256 2248 2236 2261 2294 2273 2265 2309 2356 2235 2267 2289 2292 2283 2258 2187 2231 2237 2277 2393 2386 2283 2291 2362 2354 2295 2277 2278 2279 2269 2245 2266 2253 2250 2247 2236 2299 2249 2265 2377 2263 2263 2239 2280 2252 2261 2269 2299 2256 2256 2262 2254 2289 2267 2200 2296 2407 2223 2247 2351 2306 2295 2206 2345 2271 2275 2300 2301 2349 2303 2228 2311 2273 2278 2223 2283 2309 2235 2286 2271 2245 2246 2257 2250 2305 2260 2249 2269 2250 2251 2227 2425 2304 2293 2270 2314 2351 2278 2213 2255 2240 2245 2214 2238 2354 2246 2215 2275 2332 2216 2221 2227 2206 2273 2215 2312 2235 2221 2277 2286 2252 2189 2244 2323 2310 2277 2262 2229 2275 2247 2253 2277 2300 2251 2214 2251 2239 2300 2268 2323 2214 2288 2248 2258 2308 2215 2216 2339 2256 2193 2252 2221 2197 2265 2271 2303 2259 2289 2298 2293 2295 2273 2218 2309 2239 2293 2237 2237 2270 2283 2243 2204 2235 2284 2282 2286 2261 2290 2253 2220 2276 2263 2292 2328 2297 2270 2264 2209 2255 2246 2204 2253 2261 2337 2230 2223 2242 2292 2272 2324 2323 2240 2279 2232 2302 2317 2273 2337 2227 2240 2203 2284 2235 2273 2230 2314 2327 2290 2274 2312 2203 2246 2280 2328 2365 2217 2283 2261 2298 2207 2245 2238 2305 2279 2200 2226 2302 2248 2246 2215 2309 2327 2293 2269 2281 2276 2235 2237 2360 2241 2264 2288 2342 2286 2264 2328 2327 2284 2272 2263 2361 2253 2295 2372 2250 2272 2291 2280 2266 2254 2253 2222 2315 2268 2222 2262 2352 2260 2239 2329 2329 2290 2238 2248 2286 2268 2277 2271 2250 2265 2228 2272 2267 2310 2284 2279 2251 2230 2260 2206 2241 2315 2269 2268 2269 2241 2266 2263 2323 2247 2290 2265 2290 2273 2231 2185 2253 2271 2246 2279 2289 2343 2301 2276 2298 2265 2248 2262 2300 2279 2207 2221 2292 2259 2266 2325 2293 2203 2297 2252 2262 2261 2293 2278 2332 2371 2238 2280 2293 2278 2289 2297 2286 2320 2249 2264 2274 2257 2296 2258 2328 2235 2282 2262 2282 2261 2230 2225 2327 2305 2297 2256 2313 2290 2226 2307 2300 2306 2259 2240 2245 2226 2283 2341 2348 2260 2263 2316 2284 2248 2241 2297 2270 2262 2256 2289 2329 2328 2238 2285 2320 2286 2225 2278 2295 2314 2325 2314 2303 2252 2329 2329 2265 2280 2251 2248 2259 2284 2283 2276 2238 2211 2317 2360 2318 2230 2228 2269 2281 2309 2203 2224 2301 2285 2255 2300 2263 2243 2297 2309 2336 2312 2270 2242 2297 2326 2261 2261 2271 2334 2276 2363 2265 2316 2289 2306 2305 2300 2247 2295 2261 2274 2330 2245 2265 2291 2260 2285 2321 2269 2243 2230 2310 2282 2272 2298 2348 2303 2260 2276 2306 2243 2252 2270 2311 2255 2271 2285 2271 2284 2299 2277 2374 2314 2247 2275 2301 2237 2263 2290 2331 2268 2233 2270 2343 2350 2291 2244 2227 2247 2318 2235 2305 2313 2294 2314 2321 2336 2292 2321 2287 2255 2303 2319 2270 2210 2191 2295 2385 2273 2302 2297 2285 2296 2323 2295 2251 2314 2236 2216 2287 2269 2268 2298 2266 2279 2266 2226 2245 2310 2250 2271 2323 2283 2265 2279 2257 2263 2324 2283 2270 2266 2208 2321 2343 2266 2229 2282 2331 2345 2215 2251 2249 2263 2313 2296 2245 2315 2276 2298 2315 2329 2264 2349 2281 2203 2243 2273 2271 2276 2287 2273 2379 2233 2232 2244 2223 2332 2298 2301 2202 2281 2246 2296 2320 2292 2246 2250 2293 2285 2266 2235 2359 2286 2245 2231 2287 2286 2316 2307 2394 2333 2276 2263 2310 2307 2254 2260 2320 2287 2276 2302 2278 2251 2329 2340 2251 2339 2264 2283 2334 2239 2237 2234 2360 2309 2317 2316 2299 2309 2308 2219 2315 2324 2273 2253 2325 2359 2296 2327 2285 2306 2245 2248 2313 2318 2295 2223 2306 2266 2333 2326 2295 2267 2330 2251 2332 2254 2298 2288 2449 2300 2328 2326 2306 2295 2266 2228 2300 2297 2278 2308 2273 2223 2311 2314 2332 2370 2295 2285 2313 2276 2266 2361 2328 2316 2293 2283 2360 2298 2287 2316 2229 2297 2258 2381 2378 2321 2245 2248 2285 2267 2280 2360 2361 2276 2370 2320 2355 2280 2296 2258 2527 2365 2291 2319 2321 2270 2295 2241 2313 2320 2351 2368 2379 2287 2277 2270 2301 2309 2256 2240 2248 2277 2287 2334 2298 2279 2280 2300 2353 2331 2324 2369 2288 2317 2282 2306 2358 2336 2321 2253 2299 2288 2348 2272 2370 2343 2296 2252 2326 2368 2299 2305 2254 2257 2243 2271 2367 2320 2329 2339 2303 2268 2279 2245 2219 2297 2237 2303 2336 2363 2334 2273 2297 2269 2340 2290 2321 2243 2310 2360 2299 2247 2321 2285 2295 2279 2220 2278 2367 2304 2290 2303 2346 2273 2276 2353 2339 2376 2343 2297 2271 2277 2275 2356 2320 2283 2258 2287 2257 2289 2265 2279 2295 2266 2376 2285 2282 2243 2245 2337 2299 2280 2245 2299 2313 2257 2356 2328 2365 2283 2302 2291 2276 2347 2317 2312 2338 2394 2301 2315 2264 2367 2323 2339 2307 2280 2262 2311 2297 2273 2238 2260 2376 2327 2252 2321 2323 2312 2290 2345 2358 2286 2227 2264 2339 2288 2337 2226 2245 2301 2263 2263 2332 2228 2230 2284 2292 2286 2239 2259 2314 2251 2292 2262 2310 2248 2315 2292 2256 2230 2260 2269 2316 2241 2263 2361 2377 2290 2240 2318 2277 2321 2261 2354 2289 2257 2276 2301 2305 2281 2224 2272 2367 2310 2261 2264 2247 2271 2234 2343 2270 2271 2273 2276 2329 2297 2259 2358 2350 2298 2275 2281 2254 2268 2256 2320 2347 2264 2291 2318 2338 2322 2303 2300 2289 2286 2268 2266 2318 2292 2293 2295 2325 2363 2279 2335 2340 2271 2259 2278 2304 2324 2342 2321 2358 2322 2289 2299 2312 2289 2264 2332 2279 2284 2297 2310 2339 2295 2268 2287 2374 2346 2224 2295 2276 2239 2275 2286 2297 2260 2320 2260 2316 2293 2275 2301 2287 2289 2268 2287 2258 2271 2270 2316 2320 2293 2254 2295 2282 2257 2283 2264 2301 2273 2317 2271 2287 2320 2306 2306 2418 2254 2218 2408 2284 2306 2263 2307 2317 2344 2260 2290 2356 2288 2266 2318 2270 2240 2248 2292 2273 2301 2229 2308 2282 2257 2277 2257 2274 2314 2262 2271 2337 2282 2273 2311 2327 2256 2246 2273 2301 2224 2224 2287 2303 2253 2241 2267 2305 2261 2248 2300 2334 2254 2234 2237 2333 2306 2255 2220 2226 2289 2247 2226 2319 2273 2233 2278 2273 2239 2262 2251 2283 2257 2226 2252 2352 2304 2254 2271 2315 2263 2236 2304 2285 2303 2303 2315 2334 2276 2232 2224 2261 2222 2237 2274 2340 2288 2260 2246 2365 2295 2271 2272 2263 2267 2233 2234 2263 2273 2300 2287 2264 2352 2254 2302 2311 2219 2303 2323 2251 2259 2305 2229 2286 2320 2252 2258 2309 2272 2293 2283 2280 2271 2264 2237 2271 2265 2264 2234 2233 2249 2213 2299 2265 2227 2308 2277 2263 2221 2267 2286 2260 2257 2251 2330 2273 2302 2215 2338 2298 2242 2266 2240 2281 2212 2263 2260 2259 2251 2247 2213 2263 2304 2225 2340 2298 2267 2254 2251 2246 2312 2299 2307 2263 2256 2273 2327 2340 2264 2220 2285 2262 2271 2240 2278 2275 2244 2268 2256 2340 2244 2267 2229 2235 2245 2277 2263 2308 2310 2323 2304 2338 2270 2274 2307 2281 2344 2238 2264 2277 2298 2273 2274 2252 2274 2233 2250 2270 2252 2274 2257 2244 2229 2247 2272 2297 2236 2257 2318 2229 2212 2240 2281 2279 2251 2257 2307 2292 2309 2242 2306 2308 2314 2246 2297 2261 2234 2179 2246 2246 2267 2225 2255 2290 2318 2254 2223 2212 2250 2221 2245 2253 2234 2261 2379 2352 2313 2216 2241 2278 2317 2236 2236 2265 2234 2294 2226 2328 2305 2219 2326 2278 2252 2271 2272 2300 2299 2290 2290 2277 2203 2303 2267 2254 2242 2251 2267 2264 2307 2201 2309 2272 2314 2277 2304 2312 2263 2217 2214 2242 2310 2294 2294 2325 2349 2237 2247 2251 2223 2302 2331 2316 2280 2274 2256 2341 2266 2246 2259 2316 2274 2253 2280 2269 2251 2329 2339 2329 2285 2341 2299 2242 2276 2313 2328 2245 2243 2235 2245 2289 2238 2209 2246 2292 2267 2267 2268 2248 2287 2279 2308 2339 2290 2341 2268 2278 2276 2304 2252 2255 2250 2276 2243 2312 2279 2314 2286 2365 2271 2251 2242 2310 2352 2271 2331 2292 2222 2236 2289 2272 2226 2243 2309 2254 2284 2273 2264 2266 2255 2237 2238 2265 2313 2255 2278 2294 2212 2272 2304 2303 2290 2299 2269 2229 2232 2220 2236 2275 2282 2268 2236 2220 2261 2336 2327 2205 2280 2271 2289 2282 2263 2277 2220 2252 2265 2290 2259 2254 2289 2276 2310 2302 2326 2269 2276 2282 2259 2244 2294 2332 2253 2214 2258 2294 2257 2281 2302 2309 2272 2320 2321 2318 2253 2252 2269 2235 2267 2240 2274 2260 2297 2298 2350 2307 2315 2267 2304 2253 2266 2308 2316 2279 2275 2234 2297 2316 2285 2238 2314 2290 2252 2343 2355 2350 2273 2279 2305 2383 2256 2288 2310 2312 2303 2321 2339 2331 2306 2282 2317 2292 2323 2289 2262 2290 2255 2286 2310 2329 2306 2267 2258 2312 2260 2243 2201 2227 2271 2290 2273 2307 2282 2266 2263 2324 2321 2246 2392 2283 2283 2343 2322 2264 2300 2316 2248 2271 2345 2335 2339 2267 2351 2282 2340 2353 2309 2269 2325 2223 2269 2243 2271 2322 2339 2209 2300 2387 2289 2252 2311 2335 2314 2297 2282 2293 2237 2304 2265 2332 2312 2282 2343 2266 2276 2292 2275 2317 2269 2315 2269 2254 2274 2247 2288 2289 2313 2312 2263 2298 2336 2265 2310 2302 2320 2287 2264 2274 2308 2284 2258 2320 2364 2223 2326 2298 2323 2235 2298 2332 2265 2272 2284 2267 2294 2287 2262 2302 2331 2349 2304 2305 2289 2253 2342 2356 2392 2328 2291 2323 2257 2277 2234 2255 2248 2275 2257 2310 2274 2304 2348 2362 2274 2287 2309 2300 2286 2278 2321 2304 2322 2313 2322 2260 2248 2231 2318 2361 2267 2241 2346 2281 2285 2276 2309 2334 2304 2307 2336 2245 2263 2240 2271 2343 2260 2277 2294 2285 2251 2314 2280 2293 2352 2312 2214 2261 2283 2262 2236 2265 2259 2294 2311 2257 2286 2277 2303 2247 2267 2229 2372 2285 2292 2252 2245 2219 2273 2327 2314 2285 2270 2311 2337 2288 2280 2341 2324 2254 2309 2250 2279 2263 2275 2256 2239 2305 2262 2239 2229 2297 2253 2284 2244 2330 2288 2246 2249 2292 2287 2272 2338 2376 2285 2276 2270 2262 2341 2263 2255 2276 2270 2298 2323 2250 2328 2265 2202 2268 2259 2268 2299 2284 2268 2297 2311 2309 2329 2324 2286 2285 2268 2248 2255 2280 2292 2303 2267 2341 2271 2334 2326 2309 2331 2291 2291 2274 2355 2265 2309 2305 2310 2252 2245 2275 2236 2251 2261 2282 2316 2298 2257 2218 2261 2273 2268 2301 2299 2279 2247 2265 2337 2330 2276 2293 2325 2259 2295 2212 2307 2262 2216 2280 2231 2275 2289 2283 2226 2240 2255 2229 2250 2288 2293 2305 2294 2297 2270 2241 2246 2279 2251 2271 2347 2260 2278 2243 2251 2269 2311 2242 2301 2265 2226 2409 2340 2352 2251 2319 2282 2243 2239 2288 2248 2277 2253 2316 2301 2286 2318 2294 2299 2243 2334 2258 2224 2298 2286 2302 2284 2316 2316 2328 2276 2253 2275 2321 2337 2269 2313 2345 2300 2286 2274 2256 2302 2278 2307 2218 2218 2281 2281 2341 2294 2275 2251 2275 2238 2293 2318 2288 2289 2287 2185 2283 2245 2287 2245 2260 2274 2251 2305 2269 2292 2314 2335 2299 2290 2223 2268 2345 2319 2198 2223 2403 2328 2265 2311 2240 2279 2256 2245 2276 2295 2298 2237 2262 2243 2269 2285 2259 2326 2270 2316 2323 2316 2248 2317 2325 2301 2309 2308 2228 2252 2312 2291 2265 2313 2244 2282 2316 2279 2299 2246 2199 2236 2276 2330 2275 2292 2246 2249 2241 2272 2250 2356 2334 2292 2317 2298 2261 2268 2311 2274 2297 2273 2340 2305 2308 2284 2260 2374 2285 2250 2241 2279 2321 2236 2318 2258 2239 2247 2290 2347 2275 2228 2247 2260 2357 2271 2282 2346 2264 2278 2292 2284 2235 2318 2251 2292 2333 2230 2240 2346 2271 2238 2275 2287 2383 2339 2316 2349 2349 2258 2288 2315 2344 2281 2258 2239 2358 2296 2267 2273 2260 2242 2291 2256 2287 2278 2245 2296 2297 2284 2290 2250 2253 2272 2327 2256 2364 2283 2298 2328 2292 2254 2327 2242 2274 2291 2301 2271 2233 2218 2254 2238 2318 2266 2279 2362 2226 2285 2361 2458 2277 2332 2338 2264 2283 2231 2269 2300 2332 2329 2258 2318 2274 2278 2293 2286 2276 2328 2262 2287 2336 2303 2291 2271 2255 2280 2274 2286 2323 2244 2319 2335 2341 2289 2292 2293 2317 2285 2320 2349 2362 2266 2240 2235 2257 2279 2317 2335 2302 2239 2303 2274 2289 2301 2260 2296 2273 2378 2335 2299 2335 2250 2321 2340 2219 2233 2280 2295 2395 2327 2315 2259 2288 2273 2294 2355 2329 2319 2268 2284 2312 2370 2236 2281 2292 2323 2263 2306 2256 2301 2326 2332 2313 2275 2336 2389 2305 2297 2258 2279 2285 2279 2284 2242 2276 2292 2352 2298 2340 2253 2289 2311 2258 2313 2233 2233 2225 2258 2293 2293 2292 2257 2224 2321 2294 2262 2322 2309 2284 2260 2274 2304 2285 2311 2341 2255 2296 2298 2268 2327 2303 2351 2289 2257 2284 2316 2300 2286 2287 2269 2274 2244 2274 2267 2276 2314 2245 2237 2253 2272 2225 2222 2235 2301 2299 2290 2305 2228 2287 2247 2352 2309 2212 2270 2245 2280 2284 2267 2318 2340 2340 2316 2227 2276 2312 2278 2313 2298 2245 2303 2238 2286 2365 2275 2296 2275 2276 2250 2244 2280 2256 2311 2345 2305 2311 2253 2306 2293 2254 2304 2299 2294 2269 2246 2294 2320 2354 2297 2260 2292 2280 2253 2255 2346 2304 2239 2261 2251 2259 2281 2318 2253 2279 2320 2239 2305 2235 2279 2276 2286 2245 2259 2335 2282 2263 2292 2291 2311 2298 2296 2245 2290 2287 2293 2356 2310 2357 2288 2267 2326 2378 2269 2245 2266 2259 2248 2257 2213 2303 2318 2272 2240 2316 2295 2307 2305 2242 2261 2268 2265 2262 2256 2312 2296 2317 2303 2274 2285 2243 2335 2300 2292 2269 2302 2222 2275 2275 2310 2314 2358 2280 2330 2256 2259 2283 2288 2286 2253 2249 2316 2257 2337 2352 2273 2350 2342 2302 2313 2277 2335 2292 2306 2312 2298 2355 2256 2228 2377 2291 2247 2235 2227 2238 2297 2282 2207 2267 2285 2276 2310 2313 2305 2356 2355 2306 2317 2249 2274 2286 2262 2292 2329 2389 2277 2318 2264 2288 2292 2278 2308 2323 2250 2220 2258 2271 2245 2338 2309 2321 2321 2290 2230 2245 2305 2288 2250 2314 2306 2304 2313 2345 2302 2288 2314 2246 2306 2317 2304 2367 2278 2289 2270 2313 2318 2267 2279 2367 2318 2325 2257 2332 2238 2264 2274 2258 2319 2318 2312 2323 2235 2273 2276 2243 2295 2272 2269 2263 2249 2248 2309 2303 2339 2378 2347 2307 2327 2288 2332 2269 2270 2310 2330 2352 2284 2290 2289 2280 2253 2303 2296 2288 2277 2291 2287 2342 2258 2291 2276 2286 2263 2304 2270 2300 2277 2336 2307 2334 2291 2218 2267 2306 2288 2298 2299 2319 2284 2316 2290 2298 2340 2317 2320 2322 2287 2279 2345 2279 2303 2278 2325 2294 2253 2279 2335 2348 2288 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 2276 65533 

>
```

The commands I'm sending are 'aA' to change the data mode to ASCII, 'I200' to set the integration time to 200 ms, and 'S' to acquire a spectra. Each of these commands is followed by a carriage return. Now, here is my sample code in Python, attempting to do the same thing:

```
import serial
import time

port = 'COM9'
baud = 152000

spectro = serial.Serial(port, baud)

spectro.write('aA\r')
print spectro.read(10)
spectro.write('I200\r')
print spectro.read(10)
spectro.write('S\r')
time.sleep(0.5)
print spectro.read(100)

spectro.close()
```

However, when running the Python code, the return is this:

```
>>> 
'[$;üü
 ÿÛ$;ü„Û$;
üüÃÿ[$;ü„[$;üü
>>>
```

I've double-checked that the port, baudrate, parity, bite size, and stopbits are all correct. I've also tried it with and without the sleep function between sending the command to acquire the spectra and actually reading for it. I can't think of anything else to change as far as serial connection settings. Any help would be appreciated in determining why the return is perfect in Termite but gibberish in Python. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your baud rate is wrong. Should be `115200`, not `152000`.

Comment: Thank you very much for catching that. It's amazing what we can miss once tunnel-vision sets in.

Comment: ... and, because 152000 is probably not a supported rate, your serial port was probably actually running at its default rate.